# Equivalent gray value of a color given the LAB values

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, image-processing, colors, grayscale

I have an RGB image and I converted to La*b* colorspace. Now, I want to convert the image in LAB space to grayscale one. I know L NOT = Luminance.
So, any idea how to get the equivalent gray value of a specific color in lab space?

I'm looking for a formula or algorithm to determine the equivalent gray value of a color given the LAB values.

Comment: @MichaelTr7  I'm looking to a way to directly convert an image in LAB space into grayscale one. (without converting it to any other spaces)

Comment: Kinda an odd question because colour space conversions are essentially a set of formulas/matrix multiplications.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 Do you mean it is impossible and I have to convert it to another space , such as RGB?

Comment: Why does L not equal to luminance. According to the MATLAB documentation it seems it does: [CIE 1976 L*a*b*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/understanding-color-spaces-and-color-space-conversion.html)

Comment: Not quite sure, but I don’t see the harm in doing so, unless you’re constrained and cannot.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 To the best of my knowledge, L is a nonlinear and it represents the perceived lightness, while luminance Y is a linear measure of light.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion from Luminance `Y` to Lightness `L*` is defined by the CIE 1976 Lightness Function. Put another way, `L*` transforms linear values into non-linear values that are perceptually uniform for the Human Visual System (HVS). With that in mind, your question is now dependent on what kind of gray you are looking for, if perceptually uniform and thus non-linear, the Lightness channel from CIE L*a*b* is actually that of CIE 1976 and is appropriate. If you need something linear, you  would have to convert back to CIE XYZ tristimulus values and use the `Y` channel.

Comment: Interesting! So you suggest me to convert it back to CIE XYZ to get a linear gray value. (That indicates that we cannot identify Y from LAB space)

Comment: Correct! `Y` is Luminance which is an intrinsically linear photometric quantity.